# How can I convert this string '2012-07-06T21:00:00.000Z' To datetime format to calculate the age

Tags: python, datetime, type-conversion

So I have a dataframe that has the date of birth written as a string `'2012-07-06T21:00:00.000Z'` (example).

I want to calculate the users' age from that. Note that this is a string and I think I need it to be datetime to be able to calculate it.

Thank you much

my code (Python):

```
def calculate_age(born):
    born = datetime.strptime(born, "%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M:%S.%f%Z").date()
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

df['age'] = df['birth_date'].apply(calculate_age)
```

Comment: Have a look at the library ```dateparser```. this can help if you dont have a predefined format

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import pandas as pd

df['birth_date'] = df['birth_date'].astype('datetime64[ns, UTC]')
df['age'] = pd.Timestamp.utcnow() - df['birth_date']
df['age_str'] = df['age'].apply(lambda td: f'{td.days//365}y{int((td.days/365 - td.days//365)*365/30)}m')
```

Here, you first convert the `birth_date` column to `datetime` dtype, then you calculate the time delta using current time.
Finally you calculate from days the number of years and month.